# How to move queued queries to a separate Snowflake warehouse?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake Documentation says:

> If the running query load is high or there’s queuing, consider starting a separate warehouse and moving queued queries to that warehouse.

I have the following queries:

- How do you move the queued queries to a separate Snowflake warehouse?
- Is there a SQL statement to move the queued queries? Or I have to cancel the queued queries and run them again to separate Snowflake warehouse.

Please, provide some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't move queued queries to a new warehouse, you would have to cancel and restart them on the new warehouse.
2. Alternatively you can use Snowflake's multi-clustering warehouse feature to allow more parallel execution of queries.